# Globally configure NPM with a token registry to a specific scope (@organisation)

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-private-modules

I want to globally setup an NPM registry for a specific [scope](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope) to be used with a specific [token](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/118393368555/deploying-with-npm-private-modules).

I know that I can use :

```
$ npm login --scope=@organisation
```

And I can also write a `~/.npmrc` with :

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=XXXX
```

But what I want is a combinaison of the two methods: Using the token at when assigning the registry URL to my scope.

I tried :

```
npm config set @organisation:registry https://registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=XXXX
```

But when running an NPM command (eg `npm install @organisation/my-package`). I get the following error :

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.2/bin/node" "/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.2/bin/npm" "install" "@organisation/my-package"
npm ERR! node v6.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! you do not have permission to publish ":_authToken=XXXX". Are you logged in as the correct user? : :_authToken=XXXX
```

Is there a solution? (I need to use a token and no env variable).

PS: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7995#issuecomment-175915766 but it's not working...

Answer (score 82, accepted):

According to the official documentation you should be able to [associate a scope with a registry when logging in](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope#associating-a-scope-with-a-registry). Is this what you want?

Did you try the following?

```
npm login --registry=https://reg.example.com --scope=@myco
```

If you dont want to login, but rather want to **specify the token explicitly**, the following should work:

```
npm config set @myco:registry https://reg.example.com
npm config set //reg.example.com/:_authToken xxxxxxxx
```

Note that the registry url must be normalized for this to work, ie it shouldn't include scheme and must end with a slash.

Comment: Having problems doing npm install through token. are the quotes '' supposed to be there, and the sample registry url above looks like it doesn't end with a slash

Comment: Just to add: 'npm config set' will just put these two line put this into  ~/.npmrc

Comment: What if npm is your registry? You just want a token only for a specific scope?